# Nested For loop in C#

Tags: c#

Hi guys please help me i want to print something output like this in the for loop

```
*******
******
*****
****
***
**
C

*
**
***
****
*****
******
0000000
********
```

This is my code

```
  int i;
        int i2;
        int j;
        int j2;

        for (i = 10; i >= 1; i--)
        {
            for (j = 0; j < i; j++)
            {

            Console.Write("*");

            }
           Console.WriteLine();
        }
        for (i = 0; i < 1; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("C");
        }
        Console.WriteLine();

        for (i2 = 0; i2 < 10; i2++)
        {
            for (j2 = 0; j2 < i2; j2++)
            {
                Console.Write("*");
            }

            Console.WriteLine();
        }

        for (i = 0; i < 6; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("C");
            Console.WriteLine();
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
```

Please help me with this. This is not may assignment i'm new at C# thank you to all

Comment: check your logics buddy

Comment: My best tip for you is to LEARN how to use DEBUG mode. if you know how to control the debugger (line by line, and be aware of all the values in every variable) you'll be able to make this task work yourself.

Comment: looks like homework to me

Comment: check this 
https://dotnetfiddle.net/XmtLf1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bit cleaner (and faster) solution would be:

```
for (int i= 7; i>=0; i--)
{
    if (i == 1)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(new string('C', i));
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine(new string('*', i));
    }
}

for (int j = 1; j<9; j++)
{  
    if (j == 7)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(new string('0', j));
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine(new string('*', j));
    }
}
```

fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/PGhtpp

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
for(i=7;i>0;i--)
{
    for(j=0;j<i;j++)
    {
        if(i==1)
            Console.Write("C");
        else
            Console.Write("*");
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
} //will print the inverted triangle

for(i=1;i<9;i++)
{
     for(j=0;j<i;j++)
     {
         if(i==7)
             Console.Write("0");
         else
             Console.Write("*");
     }
     Console.WriteLine();
} //will print the straight triangle
```

This should work. Hope this helps. :)

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer my problem now is fixed thanks.

Comment: well then would you please mark it as the answer @Jhayphie

Answer (score 0):

you can use below menioned code for your prob

```
 int i;
        int i2;
        int j;
        int j2;

        for (i = 7; i > 1; i--)
        {
            for (j = 0; j < i; j++)
            {

                Console.Write("*");

            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
        for (i = 0; i < 1; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("C");
        }
        Console.WriteLine();

        for (i2 = 0; i2 < 9; i2++)
        {
            for (j2 = 0; j2 < i2; j2++)
            {

                if (i2 == 7)
                {

                    Console.Write("0");

                }
                else
                {
                    Console.Write("*");
                }
            }

            Console.WriteLine();
        }



        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```